# How to reset interval counter and restart interval with counter from zero

Tags: jquery, loops, counter, setinterval, intervals

Using the following code, my interval does reset when i don't call interval again, but when i call interval again the counter doesn't start from zero, instead it continues counting.

**CODE**

```
var i=0;
var counter=0;

var play_int = setInterval(function(){ event_play() }, 4000);

function clear_event_play(){
    clearInterval(play_int);
}       

function replay_events(){
    setInterval(function(){ event_play() }, 4000);
}   

function event_play(){
    counter+=30;    
    i++;
    alert (i);
    if (i > 4){
        clear_event_play();
        replay_events();
    }
    var event_id = $('.stnby_pstr_cntr'+i+'').attr("data-eventid");
    ....
```

Where am I missing it?

Comment: You are only storing the reference to the interval created on the first call to `setInterval`, but not for the call inside `replay_events` – so you will not be able to clear the intervals created there any more. And I don’t see you resetting the value of `counter` anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reinitialize all the variables when you call `replay_events`.

```
function replay_events(){
    counter = 0;
    i = 0;
    play_int = setInterval(function(){ event_play() }, 4000);
}
```